# Google Calendar API with a Service Account Problems

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, google-api, google-calendar-api

I've been trying for days to get Google's Calendar PHP API working on my local Laravel development site. Here's the problem:

I'm using a service account so I can perform functions on **one** calendar (the service accounts calendar). I'm not authenticating users and requesting access to their calendar.

I've verified everything from my client ID, the service email address, the `key.P12` file, still nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
    $key = File::get($this->key);

    $credentialObj = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $this->serviceAccountName,
        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'),
        $key,
        'notasecret'
    );

    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName($this->applicationName);
    $client->setClientId($this->clientId);
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($credentialObj);

    \session_start();

    $calendarServiceObj = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    $events = $calendarServiceObj->events->listEvents('mygmail@gmail.com');

    dd($events->getItems());
```

I've even tried using Google's own example here:

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php

No errors, nothing. Just a blank error page every single time. I've tried so many examples all over the internet, even here on stack overflow, and at the end, all I get is a 'This webpage is not available'. This happens on every browser.

[image]

Laravel is set to development mode so all errors are displayed, and I've even force set the ini using `ini_set("display_errors", 1);`.

I know everything works fine up until I request **anything** from the service object. All the calendar api's are set to `on` in my developer account. Does my local development domain need to have SSL enabled?

It be so nice if I could figure out at least what is going on, but with this obscure error, I have no idea.

If anyone has any tips, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!!

EDIT: I've scoured through googles API code, and this is exactly where the request fails:

`vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Signer\P12.php`

Line 77 to 92:

```
public function sign($data)
  {

    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') < 0) {
      throw new Google_Auth_Exception(
          "PHP 5.3.0 or higher is required to use service accounts."
      );
    }
    $hash = defined("OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256") ? OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256 : "sha256";
    //If I die(); here, I receive the response
    if (!openssl_sign($data, $signature, $this->privateKey, $hash)) {
     //Something happens here, or inside the openssl_sign command, I never reach the exception
      throw new Google_Auth_Exception("Unable to sign data");
    }
    //It never reaches here
    return $signature;
  }
```

In my PHP Info:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating PHP. I was using Softaculous AMPPs 2.3 with PHP 5.4.27. Upgrading to AMPPs 2.6 fixed the issue. My Open SSL in my config is now:

[image]

Nothing was done to my code above since, and it now works. This was definitely an open ssl issue. Anyone receiving an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET must update their open_ssl version.

I hope this helps anyone trying to figure this out.